# How to control this robot with a PS4 DualShock controller (Python)?

Tags: python, loops, object, robotics

I am trying to control a robot with a ps4 controller connected via Bluetooth to raspberry pi, but have a problem with the while loop I need to make it move. The robot cycles leg positions in a pattern that makes it walk. I made a successful program that uses the keyboard where holding w, a, s, or d will move the robot in the usual directions and stop the robot once released. However, the ps4 controller uses functions for input in a way that confuses me.

Here is the keyboard code:

```
from move import move, steady, steady_X
import sys, tty, termios, time
import Adafruit_PCA9685

def getch():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    return ch

pwm =  Adafruit_PCA9685.PCA9685()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    step = 1
    move_stu = 1
    try:
        while 1:
            char = getch()
            if char == 'x':
                pwm.set_all_pwm(0,300)
                time.sleep(1)
                break
    
            if char == 'w':
                move(step, 35, 'forward')
                step += 1
                if step > 4:
                    step = 1
                time.sleep(0.08)

            if char == 's':
                move(step, 35, 'backward')
                step += 1
                if step > 4:
                    step = 1
                time.sleep(0.08) 

            if char == 'a':
                move(step, 35, 'left')
                step += 1
                if step > 4:
                    step = 1
                time.sleep(0.08)

            if char == 'd':
                move(step, 35, 'right')
                step += 1
                if step > 4:
                    step = 1
                time.sleep(0.08)

            if char == 'e':
                pwm.set_all_pwm(0,300)
                time.sleep(0.1)
                steady_X()

            if char == ' ':
                steady()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pwm.set_all_pwm(0,300)
        time.sleep(1)
```

where 35 is the speed of the robot.

The controller code is:

```
from pyPS4Controller.controller import Controller
from move import move, steady, steady_X
import sys, tty, termios, time
import Adafruit_PCA9685



class MyController(Controller):


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Controller.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.step = 1
        self.pwm = Adafruit_PCA9685.PCA9685()
        self.command = False

    def on_x_press(self):
        self.command = True
        while self.command == True:
            move(self.step, 35, 'forward')
            self.step +=1
            if self.step > 4:
                self.step = 1
            time.sleep(0.08)

    def on_x_release(self):
        self.command = False



controller = MyController(interface="/dev/input/js0", connecting_using_ds4drv = False, event_definition = None)
controller.listen()
```

Where once controller.listen() is called it starts taking inputs from the controller.
Right now, once x is pressed the robot will move forward and not stop when it is released. So my question is how can I make it stop moving when x is released and the on_x_release(self) function is called?

Answer (score 0):

I might not have a direct fix to your problem because I do not have the hardware to test it out, but you may consider writing a `stop()` function where you explicitly set all motors to the 0 position *(if you use a H-bridge controller, this means setting both of the channels to off)* . Then on calling the function `on_x_release(self)`, you will set the self.command flag to False as you normally do, but also, call the `stop()` function to explicitly stop the motors from moving.

```
from pyPS4Controller.controller import Controller
from move import move, steady, steady_X
import sys, tty, termios, time
import Adafruit_PCA9685

class MyController(Controller):


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Controller.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.step = 1
        self.pwm = Adafruit_PCA9685.PCA9685()
        self.command = False

    def on_x_press(self):
        self.command = True
        while self.command == True:
            move(self.step, 35, 'forward')
            self.step +=1
            if self.step > 4:
                self.step = 1
            time.sleep(0.08)

    def on_x_release(self):
        self.command = False
        stop() # (or modify the move function to accept a 'stop' string)


controller = MyController(interface="/dev/input/js0", connecting_using_ds4drv = False, 
event_definition = None)
controller.listen()
```

On a separate note, I think this issue might be because you do not have a "default" condition where the robot does nothing. Usually the way I would go about with such a problem is to define the general behaviour of the robot as doing nothing, and define the x key as an interrupt. So, whenever the key is pressed, an event occurs, and the equivalent eventHandler is called *(think of ISR if you know microcontrollers well)* . Designing it in this way will probably give you more control.